# TypeScript Type Assertion Error: 'This expression is not callable Type '...' has no call signatures' is caused by a missing semicolon

Tags: typescript, type-assertion

This is a very stripped down version of our original code:

```js
  const start: number = 10
  const end: number = 20
  (someElement as HTMLInputElement).setSelectionRange(start, end)
```

Then there was a nice little red squiggly line under the *20*. Indicating this error: *This expression is not callable Type 'Number' has no call signatures*. We figured out the solution is to add a semicolon:

```js
  const start: number = 10
  const end: number = 20;
  (someElement as HTMLInputElement).setSelectionRange(start, end)
```

Does anyone know why it would compile that way? I'm assuming typescript being compiled into javascript is interpreting that code as below and attempting to invoke the `end` variable as a function.

```js
  const start: number = 10
  const end: number = 20(someElement as HTMLInputElement).setSelectionRange(start, end)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behavior isn't specific to TypeScript; the issue you're having is the same as you would get with plain JavaScript.  The TypeScript compiler isn't choosing to compile correct TypeScript into incorrect JavaScript; instead, it's dutifully transpiling weird TypeScript into the equivalent weird JavaScript.

In general, [automatic semicolon insertion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Automatic_semicolon_insertion) doesn't apply if the next token after the line terminator is *possibly syntactically* valid, the only exceptions being one of the specific places where line terminators are forbidden (see the MDN link above for a list of these places).  The open parenthesis `(` after `20` can apparently be interpreted as the start of a function call, which is syntactically valid.  And because a line terminator is not forbidden after `20`, no semicolon gets inserted.

In TypeScript, you get a compiler error warning you that you are calling `20` which has no call signature.  That error is a good thing, because it gives you a chance to fix your code by inserting your own semicolon, before you get to runtime.  Because again, if you were writing the above code in plain JavaScript (e.g., without type assertions), the JavaScript runtime would interpret the code the same way and you'd get a runtime error instead of a compiler warning:

```js
// This is plain JS, not TS 
try {
  const someElement = document.getElementsByTagName("input").item(0);
  const start = 10
  const end = 20
  (someElement).setSelectionRange(start, end)
} catch (e) {
  console.log("OOPS I CAUGHT AN ERROR");
  console.log(e.message); // 20 is not a function
}
```

If you run that code snippet (with no TypeScript compiler in sight) you'll see that your browser's JavaScript runtime issues a `TypeError` that `20` is not a valid function.

Comment: Well said! Thank you jcalz. Just out of curiosity do you recommend any alternate ways of writing type assertions?

Comment: There's the angle bracket syntax but that would result in a similar problem, and `as` syntax is better anyway (especially for JSX/TSX code).  My real recommendation is to just use semicolons at the end of statements.  Automatic semicolon insertion is *weird* and makes the language harder for humans to reason about.  It bites everyone at some point, I think.